# Saving webcam video frame by frame

Tags: webcam, video-capture, avconv

Is there a solution to capture the video from a USB webcam and save each frame in a local folder as a jpeg file on a linux system by using command line? Or should I use opencv?

So far I have managed to save the stream to an avi file with this system call:

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 video1.avi
```

In order to get a single frame, I can use this:

```
fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 85 -D 1 shot.jpg
```

The problem is that if I put this last command in a loop, I manage to get only about one frame per second. As the avconv command manages to save the avi file at 30fps without problems, I suppose it could manage to save also the sequence of jpeg files at 30 fps, if I found out the right command.

I know there is this command that saves single frames in jpeg from a video file and it works fine:

```
avconv -i video1.avi -r 30 -f image2 out_%04d.jpg
```

However, if I try this:

```
avconv -i /dev/video0 -r 30 -f image2 out_%04d.jpg
```

I get this error:

```
/dev/video0: Operation not permitted
```

Is there a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but in openshot you can import video and convert it to an image sequence.  The sequence is exported into a folder in the same directory and each frame is a png.  I've only used it through openshot's gui, though, I don't know the command line usage.  In the gui just right-click on an imported video file and there is an option to convert to image sequence.